# SELECTING multiple copies of some rows, single copies of others for INSERT

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

In Postgres, I want to copy over rows from a table of templates into a table of instances. The trick is, I want to make multiple copies of some rows and only single copies of others.

One example of syntax that isn't working:

```
INSERT INTO owned_instances
(
  template_id,
  owner,
  property1,
  property2,
  etc
)
SELECT
  id,
  '478aa65e-ecf7-48fb-bc20-f7fcf300aaa9',
  property1,
  property2,
  etc
FROM templates
WHERE id IN (1, 1, 1, 2, 3);
```

The intent here would be that the owner would receive 3 copies of template 1, and 1 copy each of templates 2 and 3.

This version doesn't work. **WHERE id IN** only grabs one copy of each listed **id**. Other syntaxes I've tried have been equally fruitless.

Of course it's possible with multiple insert calls, but I have to wonder if there's a tidy & efficient way to do this in a single insert.

---

Attempting to anticipate one question:
The copies in the table of instances will be individually mutated later. So the quick solve of just adding a column to count how many copies one row represents won't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track but you will need to join to a table containing the `id` values:

```sql
INSERT INTO owned_instances (template_id, owner, property1, property2, etc)
SELECT
    i.id,
    '478aa65e-ecf7-48fb-bc20-f7fcf300aaa9',
    t.property1,
    t.property2,
    t.etc
FROM templates t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
) i
    ON i.id = t.id;
```

Comment: That inserts 5 copies of EVERY row in the templates table, not 3 copies of row 1, etc..

Comment: @baudot Yes of course you are correct, I have fixed the problem by switching to an inner join.

Comment: Ah, yes, that works.